# What is the win32 API function for private bytes?

Tags: windows, winapi

What is the win32 API function for private bytes (the ones you can see in perfmon).

I'd like to avoid the .NET API

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the .NET API?

Comment: No technical reason; I'm just asking :)

Answer (score 15):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessMemoryInfo(
  __in   HANDLE Process,
  __out  PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters,
  __in   DWORD cb
);
```

Where `ppsmemCounters` parameter can be a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` or `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` structure. Just typecast `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` to `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`.

`PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX.PrivateUsage` is what you're looking for.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219(VS.85).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684874(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the same data perfmon shows using the [performance counters API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what you are trying to do. These are internal figures whose value is not   really controlled by any API.

Technically Private Bytes is the commit charge, the amount of memory allocated in the swap file to hold the contents of the applications private memory should it be swapped out.

Generally private bytes = amount of dynamically allocated memory + some extra.