# How to get Private Working Set Memory for process in C++

Tags: c++, windows, memory, process

I am interested in monitoring memory usage for a process, much like in the Task Manager, given the process ID on windwos platform. After reading this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process) and reading up on the [PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/ns-psapi-process_memory_counters) I was able to come up with the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>

SIZE_T getMemoryUsage(DWORD Process_PID) {
  MEMORYSTATUSEX memInfo;
  memInfo.dwLength = sizeof(MEMORYSTATUSEX);
  GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);

  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS PMC;
  HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, Process_PID);
  GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, (PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS *)&PMC, sizeof(PMC));

  SIZE_T physicalMemUsedByProc = PMC.WorkingSetSize;

  return physicalMemUsedByProc;
}
```

However, it only measures Working Set, while what is shown in Task Manager as memory is Private Working set. My question is how can I obtain the Private Working set value if I have Working Set one? Is using PROCESS_MEMORY_COUTNERS a good approach, or should I consider something else for this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/560476/920069 You need to pass a `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX` struct.

Comment: Don't tag C++ questions with the C tag unless you really like downvotes.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for taking time to answer. Can you please explain a little bit more in details? I am fairly inexperienced in C++, especially when it comes to windows related stuff. I tried something akin to that in order to get PrivateUsage statistic from PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX struct, but the value still doesn't match what I could see in Task Manger.

Comment: I don't know how Task Manager reports memory usage. I just linked the answer that showed how to get the additional stat. You might get something closer using Performance Counters, or not. *shrug*